# Creating and Writing to a file on Android

Tags: android, opencsv

I'm new to programming in android. I'm trying to create a csv file in the shared storage of the android device. I then want to add lines to that file based on user inputs. It looks like with android 11 the process of creating and editing file on shared storage has changed and i'm quite confused on how to accomplish it.

So far I have been able to create a csv file but I can't seem to edit it in any way. This is the code I used to create the csv file:

```
File baseDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
Uri baseDirUri = Uri.fromFile(baseDir);
String fileName;
String noteFile;   
private void createFile() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("application/csv");
    String currentTime = getPhoneTime();
    fileName = "notes_" + currentTime + ".csv";
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, fileName);
    
    // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
    // the system file picker when your app creates the document.
    intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, baseDirUri);
    
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    noteFile = baseDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName;
    writeToCsv("Time;ROS Time;Event;Team;Description;Ticket");
}
```

I then use openCSV to try and write to the csv File:

```
private void writeToCsv(String line) {

    try {
        // create FileWriter object with file as parameter
        FileWriter outputfile = new FileWriter(noteFile);

        // create CSVWriter object filewriter object as parameter
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile);

        writer.writeNext(line.split(";"));

        // closing writer connection
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the file is empty when I go to view it. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are writing to a file path that has nothing to do with ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT.

Comment: Your startActivituForResult should be accompanied by onActivituResult implementation.

Comment: Further if you had put a Toast() in that catch block to inform the user...